# How to extract data from a single cell into multiple columns using scala in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with space delimiter in my column "_raw"

I need to extract data from this column into multiple columns

"_raw" column:

```
Device          rReq_PS      wReq_PS        rKB_PS        wKB_PS  avgWaitMillis   avgSvcMillis   bandwUtilPct

sda                7.00         0.00         64.00          0.00           8.71           8.43           5.90

sdc                0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

sdb                5.00        10.00         32.00         40.00           2.67           2.67           4.00

dm-0               1.00         0.00          8.00          0.00           9.00           9.00           0.90

dm-1               6.00         0.00         56.00          0.00           8.67           8.33           5.00

dm-2               5.00        10.00         32.00         40.00           2.67           2.67           4.00
dm-3               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

dm-4               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

dm-5               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

dm-6               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

dm-7               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

dm-8               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00

dm-9               0.00         0.00          0.00          0.00           0.00           0.00           0.00
```

I was able to extract with a specific string but unable to get it with all the strings

```
val log = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .option("multiLine", "true")
      .load("query4.csv").cache()

    log.createOrReplaceTempView("logs")
    val df = spark.sql("select _time, _raw, host from logs")

    import spark.implicits._
    val extractbandwUtilPct
    = udf{(raw: String) => raw
      .split("\n")
      .map(_.split(" +"))
      .find(_(0) == "sda")
      .map(_(7)).getOrElse("unknown")}



    val extractedData = df.filter(
      $"host" === "ausflscgap01.us.dell.com" ||
        $"host" ==="ausflscgap02.us.dell.com" ||
        $"host" === "ausplscgap01.us.dell.com" ||
        $"host" === "ausplscgap02.us.dell.com")
      .withColumn("bandwUtilPct", extractbandwUtilPct($"_raw")).drop("_raw").show()
```

I need to extract the _raw column with two new columns "Device" and "bandwUtilPct"

```
Device  bandwUtilPct
sda     5.90
sdc     0.00
sbd     4.00
dm-0    0.90
dm-1    5.00
dm-2    4.00
dm-3    0.00
'
'
'
dm-9    0.00




import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, _}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object IOSTAT_extracted_data {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("IOSTAT")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val log = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("multiLine", "true")
      .load("query4.csv").cache()

   val df = log.select("_time", "_raw", "host").toDF()

    import spark.implicits._
    case class RawInfo(Device: String, bandwUtilPct: String)

    val extractRawInfo = udf{raw: String =>
      val all = raw
        .split("\n")
        .map(_.split(" +"))
        .find(_(0) == "sda")

      def getValue(pos: Int) = all.map(_(pos)).getOrElse("unknown")

      RawInfo(
        Device = getValue(0),
        bandwUtilPct = getValue(7))
    }

    val extractedData = df.filter($"host".isin("ausflscgap01.us.dell.com", "ausflscgap02.us.dell.com", "ausplscgap01.us.dell.com", "ausplscgap02.us.dell.com"))
      .withColumn("info", extractRawInfo($"_raw"))
      .select("info.device", "info.bandwUtilPct", "host", "time")
      .drop("info")
      .show()

//    extractedData.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("sep", ",").option("multiLine", "true").save("IOSTAT_extracted_data")
  }
}
```

Comment: adding @skotlov for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return several values from udf: Array[...] or case class.
Personaly, I prefer case classes like this:

```
case class RawInfo(device: String, bandwUtilPct: String)

val extractRawInfo = udf{(raw: String) =>
      val all = raw
        .split("\n")
        .map(_.split(" +"))
        .find(_(0) == "sda")

      def getValue(pos: Int) = all.map(_(pos)).getOrElse("unknown")

      RawInfo(
        device = getValue(0),
        bandwUtilPct = getValue(7))
    }

    df.filter($"host".isin("ausflscgap01.us.dell.com", "ausflscgap02.us.dell.com", "ausplscgap01.us.dell.com", "ausplscgap02.us.dell.com"))
      .withColumn("info", extractRawInfo($"_raw"))
      .select(......, "info.device", "info.bandwUtilPct")
      .show()
```

Comment: I get these below errors when i try your solution. Please see the edit

Error:(25, 29) No TypeTag available for RawInfo
    val extractRawInfo = udf{raw: String =>

Error:(25, 29) not enough arguments for method udf: (implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[RawInfo], implicit evidence$4: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String])org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction.
Unspecified value parameters evidence$3, evidence$4.
    val extractRawInfo = udf{raw: String =>

Comment: Move the definition of case class RawInfo(...) outside of the main method.

Comment: I am able to get results for "sda" only how do i include the other rows?

Comment: Return array of RawInfo from udf: Seq(RawInfo(...),RawInfo(...))      and explode info after: df.withColumn("info", explode(extractRawInfo($"_raw"))).select("host", "info.device", "info.bandwUtilPct").    Result df will contain separate row for each returned RawInfo.

Comment: below is what i did

Seq(RawInfo(Device = getValue(0),
      bandwUtilPct = getValue(7)))

since having the "sda" in find i guess it only returns data related to "sda". Also another thing to add is the occurrences are dynamic so if i hardcode based on the index it gives data only if the pattern is available else it does not result the actual data. Is there a way i can wildcard and returns all the columns names without specifying the string and also not with the index position?

Comment: did you get time to review this?

Comment: i wish i could get it fixed but i am very new to scala and programming too so require your help :)